This is returning the first instance rather than the last in google sheets
What I am trying to do in Google sheets is search column D for the last cell that has "English"... Then return that row from E thru BL.
For some reason, this formula is returning the first matching row and not the last:
=INDEX(E2:BL, MATCH("English", D2:D, MATCH(2, 1/(D2:D="English"))))

How would I adjust?

Use XLOOKUP with search_mode set to -1:
=XLOOKUP("English",D2:D,E2:BL,,,-1)


love your solution as well.  Thanks so much.  Is there an advantage to xlookup over index match solution?

XLOOKUP is designed to give us the ability to return the last match rather than the first, MATCH is not.

Your formula returns the first matching row instead of the last one because MATCH("English", D2:D, ... ) in your formula finds the first occurrence of "English" in column D. Then, MATCH(2, 1/(D2:D="English")) is evaluated within the range of the first occurrence found by the first MATCH function.
To fix this, modify the formula so that the second MATCH function searches from the beginning to the end of column D:
=INDEX(E2:BL, MATCH(2, 1/(D2:D="English")), )

